# Querying prometheus label values with metric values

Tags: prometheus, promql

Is there a way to get the label values as the Value of a prometheus query.
For example, i need to filter out the instances which has more than 80 % CPU usage. I need the list of ip addresses as the output. Is it possible or will the Value column will only be the metric values.

Expected output:

```
Value
10.21.123.21
72.34.128.31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using HTTP API**

You can get the instances with more than 80% of CPU usage running the following command:

```
curl --silent --globoff --request GET "http://PROMETHEUS-SERVER/api/v1/query?query=100-100*avg%20by%20(instance)(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode=\"idle\"}[5m]))>80" | jq --raw-output '.data.result[].metric.instance'
```

**Using Grafana**

If you're using Grafana you can add a variable at "Dashboard settings" > "Variables" > "New"

Query Options:

```
Data source: Prometheus

Query: query_result(100 - 100 * avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) > 80)

Regex: /.*\"(.*)\".*/
```

Comment: I am not using grafana for visualization. I need to do it with the Http APIs exposed by prometheus. I am getting the label values if i use /label/instance/values. But how to get the values that are present in the result of a query.

Comment: I added the HTTP API info.